# Compare the performance and reliability of two hard disk drives

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, performance

I currently have two basic hard disk drives from brands I don’t even recall. I just bought a new SSD to be the replacement of one of the two current ones.

> [image]

The two hard disk drives I currently have have been bought around the same time, they are about the same size. I want to test their performance in order to select keep the most performant and/or the most reliable if that can even be measured.

Is there any easy way to make such tests? I am running Windows 8.1.

Comment: HD Tune if on Windows.

Comment: Why is there a `ssd` tag? From the question, what i understand is that you need to compare the performance of the older hard drives which i believe are not ssd. Please update. Thanks

Comment: I would keep the Hitachi (HGST). In mass tests they held up a lot better than the Seagates (your ST drive). Example  ==> https://www.backblaze.com/blog/best-hard-drive/

Answer (score 1):

- HD Sentinel is the best free diagnostic that I've seen. Just run the [trial version](http://www.hdsentinel.com/)
- For benchmarking, [ATTO](http://www.attotech.com/disk-benchmark/) and [Crystal Disk Mark](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html).

Some References:

- [Free Hard Disk Drive Benchmark/Diagnostic Utility](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2095766/free-hard-disk-drive-benchmark-diagnostic-utility.html)
- [10 Free Tools to Measure Hard Drive and SSD Performance](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/measure-actual-hard-disk-perfomance-under-windows/)
- [Advanced Disk Test - Hard drive benchmark](http://www.passmark.com/products/pt_advdisk.htm)